# Canada visa application IMM5257 cannot be opened

Tags: visas, canada

I was trying to fill the IMM5257 form for visa application. But the page always said:

> Please wait...
>   If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a website, not about travel.

Comment: *IMM5257 form for visa application.* What URL? So that people can take a look...

Comment: @JanDoggen The link is here: https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5257e.pdf

Comment: @DJClayworth Oh, of course I have to use this website in order to travel to Canada. Not everyone is visa exempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found a solution. Basically follow [this link](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-open-pdf-in-adobe-reader) to ask your browser to use external acrobat instead of built-in pdf reader to open the file.